# Bootstrap/JQuery Table Filter is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I can´t figure out why the filter is not working.
This is my input filed (which is the filter) an the table, both written in pug.

```
input#myInput.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search..')

   table.table.table-hover
     thead
       tr
         th(scope='col') E-Mail
         th(scope='col') Rolle
     tbody#myTable
      each user in users
           tr
            td #{user.local.email}
            td #{user.local.role}
```

And here is the javascript document

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
     var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
     $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
       $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Your filter is working for me: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fq7o2v3d/)

Comment: Could you describe in which way the filter is misbehaving for you?

Comment: @RolandWeber it does nothing, like the javascript is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to filter table row `<TR>` and the content is inside `<td>` you need to check get by each `<td>` to find value

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var rows = $(".myTable").find("tr").hide();
        if (this.value.length) {
            var data = this.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                rows.filter(":contains('" + v + "')").show();
            });
        } else rows.show();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search here" />
    
<table class="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>lion</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mouse</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why should someone try this? Could you describe what you've changed so far?